# Extract data from text file

Tags: c#

I need to extract some data from a text file and insert to columns in excel sheet. I know how to do this if the rows and the length of the string is known.

```
try
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt")
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listSNR.Items.Add(line.Substring (78,4));
        }
    }
}
```

But the particular text file is complex and the starting index or the length cannot be provided. But the starting word (PCPU01) of the row is known. 
Eg: `PCPU01,T2716,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00`

output:
`T2716  0   0.01    0   0`

In that case can somebody please let me know how to extract the texts?

Comment: Your output is ***not*** a substring of your input. What's going on?

Comment: Please show relevant code and comments only. Your question is _"How do I parse `PCPU01,T2716,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00` to `T2716 0 0.01 0 0` please show me the code"_. That is not how it works. You need to show what can differ for the input, what you want to happen then and what you have tried to parse the input.

Comment: If you have line, you can find index of starting word (`IndexOf` method) and then read required number of characters (or if you don't know the length - you need to know pattern ending and calculate required length). You can also use `regex`es but it is going to be more complex. Try some of those ideas, and update question if you have any issues. Provide us also with sample input and expected output to help us get working solution

Comment: That looks as if you actually want to split by comma and skip the first column.

Comment: In some cases where you have to read delimited files the VB.NET TextFieldParser class might be of some help. It is particularly helpful when reading files with multiple line formats, which I think is what you're describing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split(',');
        //...
    }
}
```

`split[0]` will return `"PCPU01"`, `split[1]` `"T2716"` and so on.

Comment: @lllidan Thanks for the answer. This was useful for me

Answer (score 1):

You can split one string into an array of strings, separated by a given character. This way, you could split the source string by a comma and use the resulting strings to build your output. Example:

```
string source = "PCPU01,T2716,0.00,0.01,0.00,0.00";
string[] parts = source.Split(',');
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

result.Append(parts[1]); // The second element in the array, i.e. T2716
result.Append(" ");
result.Append(parts[2]); // 0.00
... // And so on...
return result.ToString() // return a string, not a StringBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps a little bit. You might have to tweak it to your needs. But this is a higher level code that gives you general idea of extracting data off a notepad.

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            Collection<Info> _infoCollection = new Collection<Info>();
            Collection<string> listOfSubDomains = new Collection<string>();

            string[] row;
            string line;

            // READ THE FILE AND STORE IT IN INFO OBJECT AND STORE TAHT INFO OBJECT IN COLLECTION
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
                {
                    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Info _info = new Info();
                        row = line.Split(' ');

                        _info.FirstName = row[0];
                        _info.LastName = row[1];
                        _info.Email = row[2];
                        _info.Id = Convert.ToInt32(row[3]);

                        _infoCollection.Add(_info);

                    }
                }

catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers. What i wanted is to identify the particular line in the text file and split the line into columns. So i was able to do this by calling a GetLine method:

```
string line15=GetLine(@"test.txt",15);
public string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader ssr = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt")) 
       //using (var ssr = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
                ssr.ReadLine();
            return ssr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Then i splitted this line by using the delimiter (,)

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach in C#. It takes a string input (which you can get out of a text file) and an int with which line you want to get. It then separates the string at a given seperator char to a list which in turn is then read out. If the given line number is lower than the count of the created list, the entry is given back.

```
    public string GetLine(string multiline,int line)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines = multiline.Split('\n').ToList<string>();

        return lines.Count >= line ? lines[line] : "";
    }
```